# Semantic UI React Transition Group animate first element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, semantic-ui-react

Semantic's Transition.Group example shown here https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/transition/#types-group only animates the bottom most element. How would I change it so the top most element gets animated instead.

If I press the add or subtract button in the example above the animation only applies to the last element in the list, how would I make it only animate the top most element. Or essentially make the selector opposite of default so it goes from top to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the sample code you realize all it does is to display a slice of the array based on the current length in the state. It appears to be appending / removing from the bottom because it's taking elements starting from the index 0. If you want to show it as if it's animating at the top, you just need to take the elements starting from the last element. For example, you can do this with `reverse`:

```
#8      state = { items: users.slice(0, 3).reverse() }

#10     handleAdd = () => this.setState({ items: users.slice(0, this.state.items.length + 1).reverse() })

#12      handleRemove = () => this.setState({ items: this.state.items.slice(1) })
```

Comment: If I see this right your suggestions would change the order of the elements in the array on every change, not retaining the order they were added in.

Comment: No it won't, Notice that for `handleAdd`, `items` is assigned new values from `users` (the original array), not the current state value. For handleRemove, it just removes the top value from the current state. You can try it on the page OP referenced.

Comment: I overlooked the reference to the `users` array in the Semantic UI example. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution using `reverse` would be to just reverse the array when you map through it and create the children.

```
render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (<div>
        {items.clone().reverse().map((item, index) => <div key={item}>
            { /* Stuff */ }
        </div>)}
    </div>);
}
```

Yes, it would create a new array on each call to `render`, but the `key` prop identifies an element and prevents unnecessary re-renders of the child elements, because though it is a new array, object references will still be the same. But I would recommend to use a more identifiable and unique value for the `key` prop, e.g. IDs' or slugs.

Also this way you wouldn't have to recalculate the array using `reverse` everywhere you use it, just at one point in your code.